# Confused with conditional probability question

Tags: probability, probability-theory

A population of voters contains 40% Republicans and 60% Democrats. It is reported that 30% of the Republicans and 70% of the Democrats favor an election issue. A person chosen at random from this population is found to favor the issue in question. Find the conditional probability that this person is a Democrat.

I tried solving it my way and got the answer of `.6`. I was wondering if that is correct.. I used `P (Democratic | favors issue ) = P ( Democratic and Favors Issue) / P (Favors Issue)` which gave me `((.6)(.54)) / (.54) = .6`

I have a feeling my calculation and answer is wrong.

Comment: The denominator is right, $(0.6)(0.7)+(0.4)(0.3)$. The numerator should be $(0.6)(0.7)$.

Comment: @AndréNicolas I see, can you tell me why the numerator should be that?

Comment: We want $\Pr(D\cap F)$. The probability of being a Democrat is $0.6$. The probability of favouring given the person is a Democrat, $\Pr(F\mid D)$, is $0.7$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint**: $$P(R) = 0.4, P(D) = 0.6, P(F\mid R) = 0.3, P(F\mid D) = 0.7 \Rightarrow P(D\mid F)= \dfrac{P(F\mid D)P(D)}{P(F)}= \dfrac{P(F\mid D)P(D)}{P(F\mid D)P(D)+ P(F\mid R)P(R)}=....$$